# gwt 2.0.0 in Eclipse Luna & gwt plugin version 3.8.0

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

All

I try to setup fresh `eclipse Luna 4.4.2` with gwt plugin version `3.8.0v201410302155-rel-r44`. My application uses `gwt 2.0.0` version.

When I add `gwt 2.0.0 SDK` to the plugin it says:

```
  PATH:\gwt-codeserver.jar is missing
```

What is the step to add `gwt 2.0.0` to the latest gwt plugin?

I checked I was able to work with Google Plugin for `Eclipse 4.4 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r44`. But now I cannot find this version of plugin.

Where I can get `GPE v3.7.0` for `Eclipse Luna` ?

Regards,
Oleg

Comment: For what it's worth, if you upgrade your GWT versions you should no longer have this issue.

Comment: This is not a solution at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it lives here:

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/eclipse_toolreleases/products/gpe/release/3.7.0/4.4/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.4.4.update.site_3.7.0.zip

I have no idea why they try to hide it.